# Unit test of MVC5's attribute route

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-5

Prior to MVC5 we use route table, and we can do all unit testing by using [some mechanism](https://books.google.ca/books?id=gzfFQrs_qQAC&pg=PA331&lpg=PA331&dq=mvc%20route%20unit%20test%20steve%20sanderson&source=bl&ots=EYD8fjs9ZM&sig=Ev_aNuG0QPXItAXO2EYTh1z56FM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCQQ6AEwAWoVChMIvqL16PnYxwIVTgmSCh2ErwU4#v=onepage&q=mvc%20route%20unit%20test%20steve%20sanderson&f=false) to test incoming/outgoing URL.

But with MVC5's attribute route, how can we create same unit tests?

Comment: There's nothing to unit test with attributes, because there's no logic being written.  You'd be unit testing the framework itself.  If you just want to have a test which ensures that the attribute *exists* then you can probably get it from reflection.

Comment: I blogged on unit testing routes in Web Api some time ago, can you see if that is also relevant for MVC 5? http://www.vannevel.net/2015/03/08/50/

Comment: @David: Thank you for pointing that out. Seems testing has reached that saturation point where instead of no tests, people are now writing too many tests, and testing the framework rather than their own applications.

Comment: @ChrisPratt: the routing configuration can most certainly be a valid target for a unit-test -- it still concerns an implementation. A public-facing API is a contract as well and I prefer to have my contracts supported by tests.

Comment: @David, the purpose is not to test the framework itself, but the routing configuration.

Comment: @hardywang: Sounds like the tests are going to want to use reflection then, since the configuration is declaratively defined in the definition of the class and not in any imperative logic to be executed.

Comment: You want [MvcRouteTester](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvcRouteTester.Mvc5.2/).